# Building a static C/C++ library for iOS is not an option in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, xcode5

When creating a new project in Xcode 5, I have an option to create a *Cocoa Touch Static Library* from iOS project types. However, OS X project types list *Cocoa Library*, *C/C++ Library*, *STL C/C++ Library* among others.

I would like to create a C library for iOS. I can do that by selecting *Cocoa Touch Static Library*, but then manually remove the `-ObjC` flag, the Foundation framework and a bunch of other things manually. Is there a cleaner way of doing this? Is there a particular reason C/C++ static libraries are not a good idea? I was imagining that if I can build an armv7 library it will work on more than just iOS.

Comment: It gets down to what other platforms will properly link to a static library created on a Mac with the armv7 architecture. I've developed lots of C/C++ libraries using Xcode, but they were all intended for linking to iOS or OSX executables.